# 'IsNullOrWhitespace' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, .net, string, is-empty, isnullorempty

Is there a JavaScript equivalent to .NET's [`String.IsNullOrWhitespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.7.2) so that I can check if a textbox on the client-side has any visible text in it?

I'd rather do this on the client-side first than post back the textbox value and rely only on server-side validation, even though I will do that as well.

Comment: You don't need a dedicated function for that. Just test this expression: `x.value.trim() === ''` (where `x` is a reference to your input element). This expression will return true if the value is only whitespace, false otherwise. Using a dedicated function for such a simple task is overkill. (Note: you would need to implement `trim()` for IE8 and below. This is an easy task and something that you would want to do anyway.)

Comment: well a textbox value can not be null so that is just a waste of a check.

Comment: "well a textbox value can not be null." That may be true, but a million other strings can. I have a custom knockout binding on a datepicker, and it can be null.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It's easy enough to [roll your own](http://jsfiddle.net/X52Ed/1/):

```
function isNullOrWhitespace( input ) {

    if (typeof input === 'undefined' || input == null) return true;

    return input.replace(/\s/g, '').length < 1;
}
```

Comment: g = global, i = case insensitive. Actually probably don't need the i.  By default javascript replace only replaces the first match, but with the g it replaces all instances.

Comment: Does not work with undefined. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/oHy8iVk7qio12Klpoh72?p=preview

Comment: Updated to support undefined. Your other test case is failing before it enter this method @Rhyous.

Comment: Dexter, I've given up on "undeclared". Also, I found another site that shows !input works for both (typeof input === 'undefined' || input == null). It works in my tests. Thanks by the way! Sometimes in short comments mentioning a problem, we forget to mention how much the answer helped. Your answer got me started.

Comment: Your solution is very good maybe you can add this `if (!input) return true;` in the condition to make the code simpler @Dexter

Comment: @CarlosEduardoCordón, this doesn't quite do the same thing as the code above - `!input` will return true for values like the string "false", as an example. Have a look here for more examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: @Dexter the code works very well with the change here is an [example](https://repl.it/@charliecech/isNullOrWhitespace)

Comment: Why use Regex instead of `trim()`?

Comment: This was posted in 2011, before trim() was part of the spec - but yes, you could use trim() now! (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Comment: It's funny how an 'easy enough' solution unnecessarily doubles memory requirements.

Answer (score 94):

For a succinct modern cross-browser implementation, just do:

```
function isNullOrWhitespace( input ) {
  return !input || !input.trim();
}
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/are207L0/1/). Notes below.

---

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5559461/4942583) can be simplified to:

```
function isNullOrWhitespace( input ) {
  return (typeof input === 'undefined' || input == null)
    || input.replace(/\s/g, '').length < 1;
}
```

And leveraging falsiness, even further to:

```
function isNullOrWhitespace( input ) {
  return !input || input.replace(/\s/g, '').length < 1;
}
```

[trim() is available in all recent browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#String.prototype.trim), so we can optionally drop the regex:

```
function isNullOrWhitespace( input ) {
  return !input || input.trim().length < 1;
}
```

And add a little more falsiness to the mix, yielding the final (simplified) version:

```
function isNullOrWhitespace( input ) {
  return !input || !input.trim();
}
```

Comment: This may fail with `Uncaught TypeError: input.trim is not a function` if input isn't a string.

Answer (score 3):

no, but you could write one

```
function isNullOrWhitespace( str )
{
  // Does the string not contain at least 1 non-whitespace character?
  return !/\S/.test( str );
}
```

Comment: should be `!/\S/.test(typeof(str) == 'string' ? str : '')`.  If it's not, null, undefined, any any object will return true.

Comment: I would write it as `!str || !/\S/.test(str);`

Comment: @cwolves what browser do you use where `HTMLInputElement.value` ever returns `null`?  Just because the question asker thinks "null" is a possible value doesn't mean it actually is.

Comment: none, but you're writing a generic function that may be used in another context :)

Comment: @cwolves I guess we just interpreted the "null" in the function name differently.  I took it to be "null string", not the actual `null` value.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string

Comment: This fails for both null and undefined values: http://plnkr.co/edit/zWruFu?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Try this out

Checks the string if undefined, null, not typeof string, empty or space(s

```
/**
  * Checks the string if undefined, null, not typeof string, empty or space(s)
  * @param {any} str string to be evaluated
  * @returns {boolean} the evaluated result
*/
function isStringNullOrWhiteSpace(str) {
    return str === undefined || str === null
                             || typeof str !== 'string'
                             || str.match(/^ *$/) !== null;
}
```

You can use it like this

```
isStringNullOrWhiteSpace('Your String');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `/\S/` to test if a field is whitespace, and combine that with a null check.

**Ex:**

```
if(textBoxVal === null || textBoxVal.match(/\S/)){
    // field is invalid (empty or spaces)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't check for null values

Comment: if textBoxVal is null, then the first part of your condition will throw.  You need the textBoxVal === null first.

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` is a useful string-function that JS is missing..

Add it:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"") }
```

Then: `if (document.form.field.value.trim() == "")`

Comment: String.prototype.trim is part of JavaScript since v5.1 / June 2011

Answer (score 0):

You must write your own:

```
function isNullOrWhitespace(strToCheck) {
    var whitespaceChars = "\s";
    return (strToCheck === null || whitespaceChars.indexOf(strToCheck) != -1);
}
```

Comment: This technique only works for blank strings such as "" and not for strings with multiple whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling the relevant parts of the two best answers, you get something like this:

```
function IsNullOrWhitespace(input) {
    if (typeof input === 'undefined' || input == null) return true;
    return !/\S/.test(input); // Does it fail to find a non-whitespace character?
}
```

The rest of this answer is only for those interested in the performance differences between this answer and Dexter's answer.  Both will produce the same results, but this code is slightly faster.

On my computer, using a QUnit test over the following code:

```
var count = 100000;
var start = performance.now();
var str = "This is a test string.";
for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    IsNullOrWhitespace(null);
    IsNullOrWhitespace(str);
}
var end = performance.now();
var elapsed = end - start;
assert.ok(true, "" + count + " runs of IsNullOrWhitespace() took: " + elapsed + " milliseconds.");
```

The results were:

- RegExp.replace method = 33 - 37 milliseconds
- RegExp.test method    = 11 - 14 milliseconds