# How to check if a variable is null or empty string or all whitespace in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check to see if a variable is null or has all empty spaces or is just blank ("").

I have the following, but it is not working:

```
var addr;
addr = "  ";

if (!addr) {
    // pull error 
}
```

If I do the following, it works:

```
if (addr) {

}​
```

What I need is something like the C# method [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace).

Comment: Do you really mean `has *any* empty spaces`?  Or do you mean `is all empty spaces`?

Comment: what about undefined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 210, accepted):

A non-jQuery solution that more closely mimics `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, but to detect null, empty or all-spaces only:

```
function isEmptyOrSpaces(str){
    return str === null || str.match(/^ *$/) !== null;
}
```

...then:

```
var addr = '  ';

if(isEmptyOrSpaces(addr)){
    // error 
}
```

*** EDIT ***
Please note that op specifically states:

> I need to check to see if a var **is null or has any empty spaces or for that matter just blank**.

So while yes, "white space" encompasses more than null, spaces or blank my answer is intended to answer op's specific question.  This is important because op may NOT want to catch things like tabs, for example.

Comment: Whitespace can also include tabs, other kinds of spaces, etc. Use `/^\s*$/` to catch those, too.

Comment: @Grant I purposefully did NOT do that because op said _"I need to check to see if a var is null or has any empty spaces or for that matter just blank"_.

Comment: What about using test() instead of match()?
return str === null || (/^ *$/).test(str);

Comment: @subsci Grant's suggestion would return a false-positive for a string containing tabs. Are you suggesting I change the name of the function? Ok.

Comment: @MarioLevrero I like it! `test` is also faster as I recall.

Comment: @Madbreaks I simply meant that Grant's suggestion works and has the semantics of the C# function.  You can try this and variants:    `function isNullOrWhiteSpace(str){
    return str === null || str.match(/^\s*$/) !== null;
}
var addr = '\t\t';

if (isNullOrWhiteSpace(addr)) {
    alert('yes');
}
else {
    alert ('no');
}

addr = '\thello\t';


if (isNullOrWhiteSpace(addr)) {
    alert('yes');
}
else {
    alert ('no');
}`

Comment: @subsci Grant's suggestion doesn't work, because it will match tabs which the op did *not* want.

Comment: @Madbreaks the op stated "What I need is something like this C# method: String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace".  That method treats tabs as whitespace.

Comment: @subsci You need to read the rest of the question: *"so that if it is null or has any spaces or no space, I can trap it"*.  "Something like" != "something identical to", and in this case it's the op's last sentence which describes *exactly* what he wanted.

Comment: @Madbreaks you're absolutely right, I don't know **exactly** what he wanted ;)

Comment: It think you'll find Empty Spaces on The Wall, but not in user input. This is cause for confusion here. I think the OP could have meant _just spaces_ or just _white spaces_, the latter including tabs as well.

Answer (score 69):

```
if (addr == null || addr.trim() === ''){
  //...
}
```

A `null` comparison will also catch `undefined`. If you want `false` to pass too, use `!addr`. For backwards browser compatibility swap `addr.trim()` for `$.trim(addr)`.

Comment: _"If you want false to pass too, use !addr"_ - breaks down if `addr` is zero.

Comment: why is the first one `==` and second matching `===`?

Comment: Using "addr == null" will also match undefined.   If you used "addr === null" it would only match null.  Using the === for the second match forces a match only on empty string.

Comment: @EdDowns aaaand that's why we should always use strict comparison. If a check for `undefined` is required, do so explicitly. This makes the code easier to understand and to support.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `if(addr && (addr = $.trim(addr)))`

This has the advantage of actually removing any outer whitespace from `addr` instead of just ignoring it when performing the check.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: Assuming, of course the op *wants* to remove the whitespace.  :)

Comment: Your answer will return a false positive if `addr` is intialized with e.g. an integer.

Comment: Without more information I assume the var is always a string if it's not null/undefined.

Comment: Op said "check if a variable...", and his example showed that variable being a string, but I'd assume that that's just an example to demonstrate the idea.

Answer (score 20):

Old question, but I think it deservers a simpler answer.

You can simply do:

```
var addr = "  ";

if (addr && addr.trim()) {

    console.log("I'm not null, nor undefined, nor empty string, nor string composed of whitespace only.");

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `addr && addr.trim()`? With a single `&` it didn't work for me but it does with `&&`.

Answer (score 8):

Simplified version of the above: (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32800728/47226)

```
function isNullOrWhitespace( input ) {
  return !input || !input.trim();
}
```

Comment: `console.log(isNullOrWhitespace(0));`  --> `true`

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own method Equivalent to

`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)`

```
function IsNullOrWhiteSpace( value) {

    if (value== null) return true;

    return value.replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0;
}
```

Comment: `\s` matches more than just spaces

Answer (score 4):

When checking for white space the c# method uses the Unicode standard. White space includes spaces, tabs, carriage returns and many other non-printing character codes. So you are better of using:

```
function isNullOrWhiteSpace(str){
    return str == null || str.replace(/\s/g, '').length < 1;
}
```

Comment: Op explicitly states the goal is to check for *spaces*, not whitespace.

Comment: Op says "What I need is something like this C# method: String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)". And if you r just checking for spaces don't name your function isNullOrWhiteSpace but instead name it IsNullOrEmtpy.

Comment: The C# method *would work* to check to see if a string was null or a series of spaces.  Op wanted something "like" that, but to check specifically for spaces.

Answer (score 4):

```
isEmptyOrSpaces(str){
    return !str || str.trim() === '';
}
```

Comment: Is there any need to duplicate existing answers? Or have you changed anything to the prior answers that makes a relevant difference?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's the easiest way

```
if (!addr?.trim()){
  //error
}
```

Comment: I believe it's the best solution, the question mark avoids null\undefined values in the string variable. Trim - removes all spaces around the chars and we get the complete result

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this:

```
!value?.toString().trim()
```

Which you can wrap in a function if you want

```js
function isNullOrWhiteSpace(value) {
  return !value?.toString().trim()
}

console.log(isNullOrWhiteSpace(''))
console.log(isNullOrWhiteSpace(' '))
console.log(isNullOrWhiteSpace(undefined))
console.log(isNullOrWhiteSpace(null))
console.log(isNullOrWhiteSpace('0'))
console.log(isNullOrWhiteSpace(0))
```

Easily adaptable if you wish to check only against strings

```
if (typeof(value) === 'number') throw new Error('Invalid input')
```

Answer (score 1):

I use simply this and this works for me most of the time.
it first trim the white spaces and then checks the length.

```
 if(value.trim().length === 0)
{
   //code for empty value
}
```

Comment: This question already has quite a few similar answers.

Comment: yeahh i really found others confusing

Comment: the other answers use truthy and falsy. falsy => empty string, undefined, null

Comment: is there any reasons NOT to use this approach it seems the most simple imo

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
/**
  * Checks the string if undefined, null, not typeof string, empty or space(s)
  * @param {any} str string to be evaluated
  * @returns {boolean} the evaluated result
*/
function isStringNullOrWhiteSpace(str) {
    return str === undefined || str === null
                             || typeof str !== 'string'
                             || str.match(/^ *$/) !== null;
}
```

You can use it like this

```
isStringNullOrWhiteSpace('Your String');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isEmptyOrSpaces(str){
    return str === null || str.trim().length>0;
}
```

Comment: this answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
function isEmptyOrSpaces(str){
    return str === null || str.match(/^[\s\n\r]*$/) !== null;
}
```

Comment: \s already matches a space, a tab, a carriage return, a line feed, or a form feed - no need for anything else

Answer (score 0):

Based on Madbreaks' answer, and I wanted to account for `undefined` as well:

```
function isNullOrWhitespace(str) {
  return str == null || str.match(/^\s*$/) !== null;
}
```

Jest tests:

```
it('works for undefined', () => {
    expect(isNullOrWhitespace(undefined)).toEqual(true);
});

it('works for null', () => {
    expect(isNullOrWhitespace(null)).toEqual(true);
});

it('works for empty', () => {
    expect(isNullOrWhitespace('')).toEqual(true);
});

it('works for whitespace', () => {
    expect(isNullOrWhitespace(' ')).toEqual(true);
    
    // Tab
    expect(isNullOrWhitespace(' ')).toEqual(true);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
do {
   var op = prompt("please input operatot \n you most select one of * - / *  ")
} while (typeof op == "object" || op == ""); 
// execute block of code when click on cancle or ok whthout input
```