# jquery validation not required with custom method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

This regarding the JQuery validation plugin.  I have a custom method like this.

```
$.validator.addMethod("USphoneCheck", function(value, element) {
            var phoneNumberPattern = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[-]?(\d{3})[-]?(\d{4})$/;
            return phoneNumberPattern.test(value);
        }, "Please enter a valid US phone number.");
```

This is my function call

```
 cus_phone: {
                    required: false,
                    minlength: 12,
                    USphoneCheck: true
                },
```

When I run the code without any value I get "Please enter a valid US phone number" message.

This is not required field, But I want to validate when someone entered a value. Am I doing something wrong? Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: inside your function add a condition. `if (value !== '') { //do the validation } `

Comment: You must add "OR" `this.optional(element)` within your `return` statement.  `return this.optional(element) || phoneNumberPattern.test(value)`  This simply makes it "optional". In other words, if you later wanted the field to be required, simply add `required: true` to the rule declaration without touching this custom method.  See [the answer within the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26635377/594235).

Answer (score 0):

Blank wouldn't be validated with that regex try adding a if else statement to say if its blank don't run the function or wrap the entire regex in () and place a ? at the end.

```
(/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[-]?(\d{3})[-]?(\d{4})$/)?
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. It works. Just wondering is there are any other way to do that through jQuery validation plugin? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that plugin, however I did find this for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970885/jquery-validate-plugin-dont-evaluate-empty-fields hope it helps.