# How can I make this date optional in jQuery Validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a datepicker on a previously required date field. I am attempting to make it no longer required, but I'm not seeing how to do that.

The form is using [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation). I see there is a required attribute that you can set to false, but the error appears still. Here is the code I am using:

```
setUpValidationForDates: function() {
  $('input.datepicker').each(function(i, el) {
    $.validator.addMethod('sDateFormat', function(value, element, param) {
      return String(value).match(/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/);
    }, 'Must have format YYYY-MM-DD');
    $(el).rules('add', {
      required: false,
      sDateFormat: true,
      validDateString: true,
    });
  });
}
```

The message seen about, "Must have format YYYY-MM-DD" is showing when the field is empty. I need it to validate if a value is present, but allow empty values. How can I accomplish this, as required: false does not seem to be working as I would expect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written your custom method as if the field is `required`... that is why you're getting the error message while the field is still empty.

You would need to add `this.optional(element) ||` to your custom method as follows...

```
$.validator.addMethod('sDateFormat', function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || String(value).match(/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/);
}, 'Must have format YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Now the custom method will not fire unless something is entered into the relevant field.

This edit to the custom method simply makes it "optional".  In other words, if you later wanted the field to be `required`, simply add `required: true` to the rule declaration without touching this custom method.

---

Secondly, you only need to declare `addMethod` ***once*** to create the new method.  It should be taken out of your `.each()` as it's unnecessarily being called repeatedly.  You can also remove `required: false` as it's already the default behavior of the `required` rule.

```
setUpValidationForDates: function() {

    $.validator.addMethod('sDateFormat', function(value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || String(value).match(/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/);
    }, 'Must have format YYYY-MM-DD');

    $('input.datepicker').each(function(i, el) {
        $(el).rules('add', {
            // required: false, // don't need this anymore, it's default
            sDateFormat: true,
            validDateString: true
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Excellent feedback. Thanks for the tips on refactoring everything. I've managed to fix the problem - I appreciate your help. It also turns out that `validDateString` is a validation method defined in a completely different file that also enforces the field be mandatory. I was ignorant of that - trying to get used to a new code base!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value is null before you valid it with regex. return true if null. Or you could update your regex to include a space so its still considered valid if only containing empty string.

Comment: I replaced the regex with this: `return String(value).match(/^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})|^$/);` (which I think is right) - Still results in an error. I think this has brought to my attention a second validation applied to the same field for some reason though.