# Javascript: using Logical Operators with Comparison Operators

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, logical-operators, comparison-operators

I am trying to understand how to use logical operators with my code and be as efficient as possible.

Let's say I have this variable:

```
var key = localStorage.getItem('keyName');
```

And this is my conditional:

```
if (key !== null && key !== '' && key !== ' ') { // localStorage key exists and is not empty or a single space
  // Do something with key
}
```

Is there a way to write it more efficiently? I tried this, but it's not working:

```
if (key !== null && '' && ' ') {
  // Do something with key
}
```

Comment: Try this

if(key) { }

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559425/isnullorwhitespace-in-javascript)

Comment: @Vamsi that works, unless `key` is `0` or `false`. Local Storage can include any type of value: http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-webstorage-20090910/#the-storage-interface

Comment: @nils, thanks for correcting me. I've never checked those conditions. Very helpful. :) I only assumed that the key would be some value, not the 2 options that u have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( value ) {
}
```

will evaluate to true if value is not:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

so `key !== null && key !== ''` can be replaced by `key`

We can use `/\S/.test(key)` to test for a string that is just spaces (1 or more)

so how about

```
if (key && /\S/.test(key) ){

}
```

or alternatively

```
if (key && key.trim()){

}
```

Comment: trim() will only work from IE9 and up but this is not an issue in your case

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use:

```
if(key) {
   // to do here
}
```

Taking care of whitespace:

```
if(key && key.replace(/\s/g,'')) {
   //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`trim()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove any leading or trailing whitespace characters from a string. There is no shorthand notation as you did in your second code example.

```
if (key !== null && key.trim() !== '')
  // Do something with key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!~[null, '', ' '].indexOf(key))
```

or

```
if(!~[null, ''].indexOf(key.trim()))
```

Explanation:

indexOf return int>=0. Int >=0 means the element is found. All result will evaluate to true except 0, that's where `~`(invert/negate the result and subtract 1) comes handy.

Rest is self-explanatory, please let me know if any further explanation is required.

Answer (score 0):

try:

`if (key && key.trim())`

the first check fails if key is null, and the second check fails if key is only whitespace.  If either check fails, the whole thing fails.